# "Target for each bar in spotfire" or "Combination of line and stacked barChart"

Tags: bar-chart, linechart, spotfire

In Spotfire:

In a BarChart is it possible to add small target lines for each bar?

A way around I have done is that I converted it to combination chart and the added a line to show the target points for each bar.
But the problem comes if my Bar chart is stacked by some column. In combination chart we have only "series by" and not color by. i.e. I cant combine a line chart and stacked bar chart.
[A related question already asked in spotfire community](http://spotfirecommunity.tibco.com/community/forums/p/2146/6135.aspx#6135)

Answer (score 3):

I have done this by putting the Category axis column in the Trellis Column axis instead. Then remove the column from the Category axis, so you get one bar for each trellis panel.

Now you can add "Horizontal line from data table" and set it to "One per: trellis panel".

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Rich. This option seems good. But in my case graph becomes quit cluttered because of higher number of categories so ended up using combination chart only.